# Stripe Payments in flutter using Dio

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, dio

Here's the method:

```
///[amount] is a positive integer in the smallest unit of currency available
///For example, for `USD` the smallest currency is `cent`
static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _createPaymentIntent(
  int amount, String currency) async {
try {
  Map<String, dynamic> body = {
    'amount': amount,
    'currency': currency,
    'payment_method_types[]': 'card'
  };
  var response = await _dio.post(paymentApiUrl,
      data: body,
      options: Options(headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $secret",
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }));
  return jsonDecode(response.data);
} catch (err) {
  print('err charging user: ${err.toString()}');
}
return null;
}
```

Everything looks alright to me but I get the response:

> Invalid request (check that your POST content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded). If you have any questions, we can help…

The parent function creating the payment intent:

```
  Future<StripePaymentResponse> payWithCard({
@required String amount,
@required String currency,
@required CreditCard card,
@required String cvc,
}) async {
try {
  int billed = (double.parse(amount) * 100).toInt();
  var paymentMethod = await StripePayment.createPaymentMethod(
      PaymentMethodRequest(card: card));
  var paymentIntent = await StripePaymentsService._createPaymentIntent(
      billed, currency.toLowerCase(), paymentMethod.id);
  var response = await StripePayment.confirmPaymentIntent(PaymentIntent(
      clientSecret: paymentIntent['client_secret'],
      paymentMethodId: paymentMethod.id));
  if (response.status == 'succeeded') {
    return new StripePaymentResponse(
        message: 'Transaction successful', isSuccess: true, paymentId: '');
  } else {
    return new StripePaymentResponse(
        message: 'Transaction failed', isSuccess: false, paymentId: '');
  }
} on PlatformException catch (err) {
  print("Transaction failed with error :::: ${err.toString()}");
  return new StripePaymentResponse(
      message: 'Transaction Cancelled', isSuccess: false, paymentId: '');
} catch (err) {
  return new StripePaymentResponse(
      message: 'Transaction failed: ${err.toString()}',
      isSuccess: false,
      paymentId: '');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var secret = StripeApiSecret;

Map<String, String> header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $secret',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

const String apiBase = 'https://api.stripe.com//v1';
const String createCustomer = '$apiBase/customers';
const String paymentApiUrl = '$apiBase/payment_intents';

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> generateCustomerID(
      String name, String email) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'phone': userData.data.phone_number,
        'email': email,
        'name': name,
      };

      var response = await Client().post(
        '$createCustomer',
        headers: header,
        body: body,
      );

      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createPaymentIntent(
      String amount, String currency, String pm_id, int cardStatus) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = intentRequest(amount, currency, pm_id, cardStatus);
      var response =
          await Client().post(paymentApiUrl, body: body, headers: header);

      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> intentRequest(String amount, String currency, String pm_id, int cardStatus){
    if(cardStatus == 1){
      // card is never used to make payments
      // thus attach payment method id with the card
      return {
        'amount': amount,
        'currency': currency,
        'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
        'customer': userData.data.stripe_customer_id,
        'payment_method' : pm_id,
        'setup_future_usage' : 'off_session',
      };
    }else{
      // payment method id is already attached with the customer id
      return {
        'amount': amount,
        'currency': currency,
        'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
        'customer': userData.data.stripe_customer_id,
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have updated my question with a parent function there too because the `customer` I get is `null`. I do get the paymentId.

Comment: First step is to create customer id, which you should generate during sign up. Adding card and making payment should be two separate steps.

Comment: In the app, I already have the user's card details. Thanks for your time though. I figured out the problem and it's that even though I'm giving it the correct headers, it is still making the request with `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to specify the content type in the Options too:

```
//Instance level
dio.options.contentType= Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType;
//or works once
dio.post("/info", data:{"id":5}, 
         options: Options(contentType:Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType ));
```

https://pub.dev/packages/dio#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that but it sill comes back to the same issue.